# how to create type in postgres (array) type using custom type

Tags: postgresql

I have custom types in oracle and then I need to populate the same in Postgres.

This oracle type creation code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE vr_return_attendee_rp AS OBJECT (
    requestid         NUMBER,
    startdate         VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION vr_return_attendee_rp RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY "VR_RETURN_ATTENDEE_RP" AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION vr_return_attendee_rp RETURN SELF AS RESULT AS
    BEGIN
        self.requestid := NULL;
        self.visitdate := NULL;
        return;
    END;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "VR_RETURN_ATTENDEE_ARR" AS
    VARRAY(10000) OF vr_return_attendee_rp;
```

---

And then I created type in Postgres like the following

```
CREATE TYPE vr_return_attendee_rp AS  (
    requestid         INT,
    startdate         VARCHAR(50)
);
```

How to create "VR_RETURN_ATTENDEE_ARR" type in Postgres.

Comment: You don't need a special "array type" in Postgres. Just declare a variable as an array of the type, e.g. `data vr_return_attendee_rp[1000]`.

Comment: If you need this type in Oracle to create a pipelined function, then you don't need all that overhead at all in Postgres. Just declare your function as `returns table (...)`

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has native support for `array` types as well as [functions and operators to manipulate them](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html).

```
create type vr_return_attendee_rp as (request_id int, startdate varchar(50));
CREATE TYPE

create table use_vr_type(id serial primary key, vrdata vr_return_attendee_rp[]);
CREATE TABLE

insert into use_vr_type (vrdata) values (array['(1, "2020-01-01")', '(2, "2020-02-01")']::vr_return_attendee_rp[]);
INSERT 0 1

select * from use_vr_type;
 id |                    vrdata
----+-----------------------------------------------
  1 | {"(1,\" 2020-01-01\")","(2,\" 2020-02-01\")"}
(1 row)

select id, vrdata[1].request_id, vrdata[1].startdate from use_vr_type;
 id | request_id |  startdate  
----+------------+-------------
  1 |          1 |  2020-01-01
(1 row)

select id, unnest(vrdata) from use_vr_type;
 id |      unnest       
----+-------------------
  1 | (1," 2020-01-01")
  1 | (2," 2020-02-01")
(2 rows)

select id, a.*
  from use_vr_type
 cross join lateral unnest(vrdata) with ordinality as a(request_id, startdate, rownum);
 id | request_id |  startdate  | rownum 
----+------------+-------------+--------
  1 |          1 |  2020-01-01 |      1
  1 |          2 |  2020-02-01 |      2
(2 rows)
```